# how to save the memory after removing the row who have the save meaning in database

Tags: mysql, database

I am creating the chat application.I am creating the database for that.

I have a question :-

If A and B are friend and i am creating the table friendship.

there is another table "users" which contain the all the user name who are using the application.each user have the unique id.

and in the friendship table i am storing the friendship between the users.The columns in the friendship table is:-

> id    user_id1    user_id2
>
> 1      a           b
>
> 2      b           a

I am storing a is friend of b and b is friend of a.
I have to repeat the to lines.
i don't want to write the lines whose meaning is same.there is any way so i can write only one row.

> id     user_id1      user_id2
>
> 1        a              b

And it specify both things that a is friend of b and b is friend of a.and through this i can save my memory.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to store is the relationship.

Then your queries and/or application logic has to treat the fact that *user1* and *user2* are in the *friendship* table as meaning that the friendship is mutual.

So if you want to find out if *a* is a friend of *b* you'll have to check your table to see if there is *a* in one column and *b* in the other.

In SQL this might look like.

```
SELECT * from friendship WHERE 
      user1='a' AND user2='b' 
    OR
      user2='a' AND user1='b'
```

If you want to get a list of all friends of *a*

```
SELECT * FROM friendship WHERE
     user1='a' OR user2='a'
```

If you want to check for 'duplicates' you can join the table to itself and check if any relationship has its reverse also present. Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM friendship f1 
   INNER JOIN friendship f2 
        ON f1.id != f2.id 
       AND f1.user1=f2.user2
       AND f1.user2=f2.user1
```

Comment: ohk and if i want to check that a is friend of b but b is friends of a or not.

Comment: @dev I don't quite understand your comment above

Comment: IF a is friend of b but b is not friend of a.and if i want to check the b is friend of a or not

Comment: Do you want to check whether they are friends both ways (always true according to your question). Or whether there is a record in your database 'duplicating' the relationship?

Comment: Yes, i want to check this

Comment: see the last query in my answer

Comment: ohk I got it.Thank you Loopo